# J2000 and J2000.0 difference?

Tags: time, definition

I've seen the standard epoch described as both J2000 and J2000.0. Is there any difference between the two designations?

Comment: They're identical.See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(astronomy)#Julian_years_and_J2000 "J2000 = JD 2451545.0 (TT)"

Comment: They are the same.  It is possible for an epoch ending with a fractional amount, which is why some people put the .0 there.  E.g. the Hipparcos catalog's epoch is J1991.25, which indicates a fraction of a year.

Comment: Also some of the Gaia data releases have non .0 epochs e.g. DR2 has the reference epoch of J2015. 5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're identical. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(astronomy)#Julian_years_and_J2000 "J2000 = JD 2451545.0 (TT)" - [PM 2Ring](/users/16685)

They are the same. It is possible for an epoch ending with a fractional amount, which is why some people put the .0 there. E.g. the Hipparcos catalog's epoch is J1991.25, which indicates a fraction of a year. - [Greg Miller](/users/25729)